# ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished error with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was trying to learn ruby on rails, so I installed the `gem` version 4.0.0, when I start my server, and go to `localhost:8000`, it brings me an error page with error message:

> ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished.

I'm using sqlite3, not MySQL. Any help is appreciated.

edit: i fixed it, had to do with my database.yml

Comment: Did you run `rake db:create` && `rake db:migrate`?

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that you have installed sqlite3 gem: `gem install sqlite3` or run `bundle install` if you have the gem listed on your Gemfile (which you should).

After that run the following commands:

- rake db:create # creates the database
- rake db:migrate # creates the tables based on your migration files

If the above two works fine, your application should be able to connect to the database. If not you probably have a configuration problem on your `config/database.yml`.